# Trying to find a username variable to creat files on the desktop said "user" is using

Tags: vbscript

Basically, the code im looking for is how to find username with a variable

```
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CreateTextFile "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test.txt"
```

I tried with other lines of code to find out the username. But nothing worked
when i typed out the code i wrote with other lines of code to figure out the %username% variable, it doesn't work.

Please respond with new lines of code attached to my previous code here. (I'm new to this so it would make it confusing if you responded with unattached lines of code.)

Comment: http://www5.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/nsw/consol_act/ca190082/s308h.html

Comment: wdym mark , why lmao

Comment: I figure they haven't thought it through.

Comment: have no idea what you mean but, does what you sent mean i could be in trouble?lol no what im using for isnt harmful, even tho its for a joke, prank fake "virus" that i make sure its risk free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write it like that :

```
strUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
wscript.echo strUser
```

And to continue with your code like that :

```
Dim fso,strUser
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
'wscript.echo strUser
fso.CreateTextFile "C:\Users\"& strUser &"\Desktop\test.txt"
```

Also,in VBScript you can get the path to the current user's desktop folder via the [`SpecialFolders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea7b5xe%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) collection:

```
WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
```

And your code can be written like that too :

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso,DesktopFolder
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DesktopFolder = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
fso.CreateTextFile DesktopFolder &"\test.txt"
```

Comment: i added a comment here. dont know where it went, but your awesome thx!

Comment: @FroggyIsDank5 [How do you accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: oh sorry, i just saw that, i just did it. but anyways thank you!